# Convert Access data base to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ms-access, ado.net

I've created an application using ASP.NET with Access DB, now I found somee.com who support only SQL Server DBs, so Now I must convert my Access DB to SQL Server DB.

Is there any tool who can do the trick ?

This is some code I'm using in my web application :

```
Public Shared Function conecter() As OleDbConnection
Dim MyConnexion As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" & System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "/Learning.mdb")
MyConnexion.Open()
Return MyConnexion
End Function

Public Shared Function lecture(ByVal requete As String) As OleDbDataReader
Dim Mycommand As OleDbCommand = conecter().CreateCommand()
Mycommand.CommandText = requete
Dim myReader As OleDbDataReader = Mycommand.ExecuteReader()
Return myReader
End Function
```

In this case, If I convert my database I must change the OleDbConnexion and other things or I can just leave them like that ?

Comment: in addition to all the answers here, try doing some validity checks on any data in your DateTime fields, if any. That's a big cause of migration problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your connection string will need to change. [Connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com) is a good resource for this if you're having problems figuring out how to set up a SQL connection string.

For upward migration, take a look at the [Access Upsize Wizard](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330468) - this link is for 2002 since I'm not sure what access version you have.

If for some reason you do not have sufficient access to your SQL database to handle an upsize directly, you'll likely need to just generate the database schema and knock out a bit of migration code.

Comment: The SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access is vastly superior to the upsizing wizard (though still not without it's own issues).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access 2007, there is inbuilt option convert access database to SQL other wise there are somany tools available for free.

[bullzip free converter](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2s/info.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try [MUST](http://www.upsizing.co.uk)

It was developed by a colleague of mine (we designed the website: www.upsizing.co.uk).

It does a fair bit more than the MS tools.